# jquery toggle class on body not working properly

Tags: jquery, vue.js

I am creating an application in vue js. In there I have two pages Dashboard and a profile. For both of these components I have one common component that is Dashboard Header(dashboardTopLeftToggle). I have a anchor tag in there, after clicking on that anchor tag I want toggle a class in body. I have already written a method in the common component and it is happening one time only means when I am in dashboard for first time or in profile for first time. After that when I am changing routes the toggle class not working. Please find the toggle method below.

```
<template>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sidebar-toggle">
    <span class="flaticon-menu-1"></span>
  </a>
</template>

<script>
import $ from "jquery";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sidebar-toggle").click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("sidebar-collapse");
  });
});

export default {
  name: "dashboardTopLeftToggle"
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it within methods since its generating dynamically using Vue renderer.

```
<template>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" @click.prevent="toggleClass" class="sidebar-toggle">
    <span class="flaticon-menu-1"></span>
  </a>
</template>

<script>
import $ from "jquery";

export default {
  name: "dashboardTopLeftToggle",
  methods: {
    toggleClass(){
       $("body").toggleClass("sidebar-collapse");
       // or without jQuery
       // document.body.classList.toggle("sidebar-collapse");
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```